# How to have the variable be assigned 'null' if no results are being returned?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Currently have a variable called VALUE that needs to be assigned a numeric value so that the stored proc doesn't error out . Currently there is no data in the database for every hour so when it reaches a point where there is no data for the prior hour, the whole procedure errors out (since nothing is being returned). Is there a way I can have *null* assigned to VALUE if no results are returned? Below is my 'SELECT INTO' code:

```
SELECT VALUE
  INTO v_PRIOR__VALUE
  FROM VALUE V
 WHERE CODE = rCode
   AND TIME = rTIME - 1/24;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or, you could actually *handle* such a situation:

```
declare
  v_prior__value value.value%type;
begin
  SELECT VALUE
    INTO v_PRIOR__VALUE
    FROM VALUE V
   WHERE CODE = rCode
     AND TIME = rTIME - 1/24;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    null; -- v_prior_Value will remain NULL, as declared in the DECLARE section

  when too_many_rows then
    v_prior_Value := -1;  -- this is just an example; you'd handle it the way you want
end;
```

Comment: thanks and haha why the italics? are my fundamentals all wrong? :(

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't say that there's anything wrong with your code. Gordon told you how to fix a problem in a simple manner. However, if someone sees such a code (select MAX(value) ...), they wouldn't know why exactly you put it that way - are you really interested in the MAX value only? But, if you leave your code "as is" and *handle* possible errors in the EXCEPTION part of your code, then a viewer knows: "aha, OK, John Wick expects that code to fail and handles possible errors that way".

Comment: I'd add using INTO without exception handlers tends to lead to unexpected failures down the road due to bad data or requirements changes unless the WHERE clause contains a unique key.

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting 0 or one rows, then I think the simplest method is aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(VALUE)
INTO v_PRIOR__VALUE
FROM VALUE V
WHERE CODE = rCode AND TIME = rTIME - 1/24;
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` (or `HAVING`) always returns exactly one row.